# Alert dialogue's Title divider's id returned null in LOLLIPOP

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

This code works good upto 4.4 kitkat installed all devices but crashes in lollipop installed devices.

```
final Resources res = getResources();
            final int titleDividerId = res.getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id",
                    "android");
            final View titleDivider = d.findViewById(titleDividerId);
            titleDivider.setBackgroundColor(res
                    .getColor(R.color.actionbartab_color));
```

It shows null pointer Exception-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Change `res.getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", "android");` to  `res.getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", getPackageName());`

Comment: tried  it but doesn't works

Answer (score 3):

titleDivider does not exist in Lollipop. The dialog interface has been changed to actually contain no title at all.
You can check for null to see if the id is maintained on the version of Android the app is currently running on. I would suggest something like this:

```
final Resources res = getResources();
            final int titleDividerId = res.getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id",
                    "android");
            final View titleDivider = d.findViewById(titleDividerId);
            if(titleDivider!=null) {
            titleDivider.setBackgroundColor(res
                    .getColor(R.color.actionbartab_color));
            }
```

Comment: Great.This is the solution i used. Sorry for late response

Comment: I wish i could up vote your answer. I dont have enough reputation, Sorry

Comment: Glad to have been of help :)